# how to change mysql_query to mysqli_guery

Tags: mysqli

I am using in a script mysqli_query but i think there is something wrong with the syntaxes. The script did work before, but changing everything form mysql_query to mysqli_query, data is not put anymore correct in the database.

This was the original query:

```
mysql_query(     "INSERT INTO download_manager (SET filename='".mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['file'])."'),
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE downloads=downloads+1");
```

I changed it with mysqli_query this way:

```
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO download_manager (SET filename='".mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['file'])."'),
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE downloads=downloads+1");
```

Can someone tell me what i did wrong?

**Update:**
My connection looks like this:

```
$link = @mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_database) or die ("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the handle stored in $link was generated from a call to **mysqli_connect** and not **mysql_connect**:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

If that fails, check for an error:

```
die(mysqli_error($link))
```

## Troubleshooting

- The **mysql** and **mysqli** PHP modules are distinct, and you can't mix functions between the modules.
- Enable [error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) to ensure you are able to see useful error messages.
- Ensure the database credentials and connection details are valid.
- Use **mysqli_error** after **mysqli_xxx** function calls to detect issues within the **mysqli** module.
- Use the @ token sparingly to avoid hiding useful errors.

Comment: Prefixing the @ token prevents mysqli_connect from reporting an error; remove that and verify that error reporting is enabled: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php